# Composer\Downloader\TransportException

Tags: ssl

When run this command.

```
composer update
```

then I got following error?

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code  
   1. OpenSSL Error messages:                                                                             
  error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol                                     
  Failed to enable crypto                                                                                 
  failed to open stream: operation failed
```

Answer (score 0):

**OpenSSH (OpenBSD Secure Shell)** in its universe repositories, which is a suite of security-related network-level utilities based on the SSH protocol

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
sudo service ssh status
```